# Some values in 1D Array not showing

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a C# program that has to copy the elements of a randomized 10*12 2D array on a 1D Array. Everything seems to be working fine. However, some of the elements of the 2D Array (last 18) would not copy to the 1D Array.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace James_Archbold_A1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int row = 10;
            int column = 12;

            int[,] twoDArray = new int[row, column];  
            int[] oneDArray = new int[row*column];

            FillTwoDimArray(twoDArray);
            DisplayTwoDimArray(twoDArray);
            StoreValues(twoDArray, oneDArray);
            DisplayOneDimArray(oneDArray);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void FillTwoDimArray(int[,] table)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = 100;
            int rndNumber;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++) //use GetLength(0) to get the size of the row
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(1); col++)  //use GetLength(1) to get the size of the column
                {
                    rndNumber = rnd.Next(min,max);
                    table[row, col] = rndNumber;
                }
            }
        }

        static void DisplayTwoDimArray(int[,] table)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", table[row, col]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void StoreValues(int[,] twoDArray, int[] oneDArray)
        {
            int rowSize = twoDArray.GetLength(0);
            int colSize = twoDArray.GetLength(1);
            for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++)
                {
                    int element;
                    element = twoDArray[row, col];
                    oneDArray[row * rowSize + col] = element;
                }
            }

        }

        static void DisplayOneDimArray(int[] oneDArray)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < oneDArray.GetLength(0); i++ )
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", oneDArray[i] );
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a 2x5 array, your `rowSize` is 2, and your `colSize` is 5. Then your loop is setting a value into the array at `[row * rowSize + col]`. The first few values of this will be:

```
0*2+0 = 0
0*2+1 = 1
0*2+2 = 2
0*2+3 = 3
0*2+4 = 4
1*2+0 = 2
1*2+1 = 3
1*2+2 = 4
1*2+3 = 5
```

So you are looping over the same values, setting them multiple times, and also not setting the last values in the array. If you have more rows than columns, I imagine you would get an out of bounds exception?

If you change `row * rowSize + col` to the correct mapping `row * colSize + col`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to copy to 1D:

```
void StoreValues(int[,] twoDArray, int[] oneDArray)
{
  int rowSize = twoDArray.GetLength(0);
  int colSize = twoDArray.GetLength(1);
  var total=rowSize*colSize;//TOTAL ITEMS IN 1D ARRAY
  for (int row = 0, d=0; row < rowSize; row++)
  {
      for (int col = 0; col < colSize; col++)
      {
          //STORE AT POSITION d
          oneDArray[d++] = twoDArray[row, col];
      }
  }
}
```

using `row * rowSize + col` will cause issue as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139543/13198).